# Modifying state in parent component with prevState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a Main.js file which contains a 'global' state. However, to modify that state that means I am placing all of my functions in Main.js to update state. Of course this means that the Main.js file is getting too large.

I am working on implementing some code splitting using React.lazy. However, I not sure how to move these functions to the children components to be able to update the global state.

The state is complex implementing various levels of nested objects and/or arrays. Because of this I need to use prevState and the spread operator to be able to modify and/or populate a deeply nested object.

How can I properly access prevState in child components to be able to safely update deeply nested objects in state?

An example of my code currently in Main.js might look like this:

```
updateObject = (objectA3, newProp1, newProp2) = {

    this.setState(prevState => {
       //some code here

       return ({
         objectA: {
            ...prevState.objectA
            [objectA3]: {
               ...prevState.objectA[objectA3]
               newProp1: "some value",
               newProp2: "some other value"
            }
          }
        })
     }
}
```

So because of the complex nature of the state I am updating, what approach can I take so that I can move these functions to the proper child component  so that I can update state in the main component.

I have come across something like [this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194990/accessing-state-from-child) that looks promising using a generic function in the Main.js component. However, I cannot wrap my head around how to implement such a mechanism for complex states.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever happen to find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to pass state up and down the component hierarchy, I'd recommend moving your state out to a store, and letting the components that need to get or set state talk to the store. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) implements this sort of pattern, but there are many ways to do this. One approach could use a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that provides state getters and setters via props.

Here's a relatively dumb proof-of-concept demo of a store with a connect method:

```js
class Store {
 connect(Component) {
   return () => <Component store={this} />
  }
  get foo () {
   return 'this is foo from the store';
  }
}

const store = new Store();

function SomeComponent (props) {
 return (
   <div>SomeComponent: Foo: {props.store.foo}</div>
  )
}

const Connected = store.connect(SomeComponent);

function App () {
 return (
   <Connected />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main concern is to avoid over-bloating your Parent component with event-handlers, what you can do is create a folder for all the utility functions you want to have for that component tree. That will let you freely bring in the necessary functions for whatever logical pattern you need to follow.

Consider a scenario like this:

You have a `Main` component which holds state and renders children:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import { handleChange } from "./utils/inputHandlers.js";

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = handleChange;

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = [
      { id: 1, text: "test1" },
      { id: 2, text: "test2" },
      { id: 3, text: "test3" }
    ];

    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  }

  createChildren = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return data.map(item => {
      return <Child {...item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createChildren()}</div>;
  }
}
```

In the Main component, we brought in a utility function, created a local method in our component and set it equal to that utility function. Then, we bound the `this` keyword from that same `handleChange` function to our component's execution context.

That step is integral for updating `state` because we need the `this` keyword to refer to our component. There's no way for the Child-component to just have an event-handler that can update Parent state, without the handler first existing in the Parent.

Now take a look at our utility function:

```
export const handleChange = function(e, id) {
  const dataCopy = [...this.state.data];

  const itemToUpdate = dataCopy.find(item => item.id == id);
  itemToUpdate.text = e.target.value;

  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      data: dataCopy
    };
  });
};
```

It looks just like a traditional event-handler, except its outside a component. Pretty cool stuff. The `this` keyword will now refer to whatever component you bounded this function to.

Lastly, you have your Child component, in which you passed down the `handleChange` method as prop, so that it can update the state belonging to the Parent component.

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, text, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={text} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-voice-yecnn